# Hibernate View showing different results in app and Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, view, sql-view

I'm working on an app in Java connected to a MySql database by hibernate.

I'm using Pojos to define the classes and using the class Session to connect to the database.

The problem is the next view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW INVENTARIO AS
SELECT
    ID_ARTICULO,
    ID_ESTRUCTURA,
    ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN,
    SUM(STOCK)STOCK,
    STOCK_MIN,
    NECESITA_REPO
FROM
    HISTORICO_INVENTARIO        
    LEFT JOIN TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO
    ON HISTORICO_INVENTARIO.ID_TIPO_MOV = TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.ID_TIPO_MOV
GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO , ID_ESTRUCTURA , ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN , STOCK_MIN , NECESITA_REPO;
```

In Java, i'm mapping the view this way:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Pojos.Inventario" table="INVENTARIO">                       

    <id name="id_articulo" type="string" column="ID_ARTICULO"/>            

    <property name="id_estructura" type="string" column="ID_ESTRUCTURA" />

    <property name="id_estructura_origen" type="string" column="ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN" />

    <property name="stock" type="float" column="STOCK" />

    <property name="stock_min" type="float" column="STOCK_MIN" />   

    <property name="necesita_repo" type="string" column="NECESITA_REPO" />


</class>
```

I've to say that the field "id_articulo" is not the ID, but i've to choose one because.

If i execute this view in MySql Workbench i can the the results correctly. If i execute the same query in my app, i'm having different results.

Does anyone knows why could be this happening?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've tried to define the XML putting the SQL in the subselect tag:

```
<class name="Pojos.Inventario">
    <subselect>
        SELECT
        ID_ARTICULO,
        ID_ESTRUCTURA,
        ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN,
        SUM(STOCK) STOCK,
        STOCK_MIN,
        NECESITA_REPO
        FROM
        HISTORICO_INVENTARIO        
        LEFT JOIN TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO
        ON HISTORICO_INVENTARIO.ID_TIPO_MOV = TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.ID_TIPO_MOV
        GROUP BY ID_ARTICULO , ID_ESTRUCTURA , ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN , STOCK_MIN , NECESITA_REPO
    </subselect>
    <synchronize table="HISTORICO_INVENTARIO"/>
    <synchronize table="TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO"/>
    <id name="id_articulo" type="string" column="ID_ARTICULO"/>
    <property name="id_estructura" type="string" column="ID_ESTRUCTURA" />

    <property name="id_estructura_origen" type="string" column="ID_ESTRUCTURA_ORIGEN" />

    <property name="stock" type="float" column="STOCK" />

    <property name="stock_min" type="float" column="STOCK_MIN" />   

    <property name="necesita_repo" type="string" column="NECESITA_REPO" />
</class>
```

Getting the worong resultset

Answer (score 0):

make your hibernate show_sql parameter to true. Now try to capture sql in your log and try to run it in your sql workbench.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Done it!

The problem was produced by the ID. I've added one extra field wich is the new ID. Now I'm getting the correct resultset